# Regex error on Visual studio?

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-2010

I'm using this url regex from  the [**RFC-3986**](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.html)

And it is written [here](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.html#page-51) :

`^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?`

It is working for me  [**here**](http://regexr.com?35p94)

But when I add it under visual studio , I see this : [image]

And chrome developer toolbar shows me this :

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

*p.s. I thought that there are maybe hidden chars - so I pasted in CMD and then re-copied it , but still....*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape all occurrences of `/` as `\/`. Then, VS will not complain.

```
var basicRegexPatterns = {
    urlPattern: /^(([^:\/?#]+):)?(\/\/([^\/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?/i
};
```

See [Escaping a forward slash in a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076229/escaping-a-forward-slash-in-a-regular-expression).

Comment: thos escaping problems  gonna kill me..... where can i find all(!) the chars which should be escaped (js)? this answer doesnt indicate `/` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions

Comment: @RoyiNamir, That answer is dealing with the regular expression itself. `/` in your question is regular expression literal delimiter (like `"` / `'` for string literal).

Comment: Oh - you are saying that the middle `/` is treated a  new regex expression....?however I found that answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17326679/859154 which shows what mdn sais which is what i asked. thanks.