# php "preg_match" mystery when using same regex on different variables - becomes the same. why?

Tags: php, regex, output, preg-match

I have tried to grab api ids for yelp, tripadviso, foursquare & twitter based on their url. I did it with regular expressions and the "preg_match" function.
however I encountered a very strange phenomenon.

```
$yelp_option = 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/belved%C3%A8re-delft-2';
$foursquare_option = 'https://www.tripadvisor.nl/Restaurant_Review-g188626-d2375308-Reviews-Belgian_Beer_Cafe_Belvedere-Delft_South_Holland_Province.html';
$tripadvisor_option = 'https://foursquare.com/v/belv%C3%A9d%C3%A8re/4ad8dc0ff964a520601521e3';
$twitter_option = 'https://twitter.com/duitdaging';

if(strpos($yelp_option, 'biz/')){
    preg_match("/(?<=biz\/).*/", $yelp_option, $output_array);
    $yelp_option = $output_array[0];
}

if(strpos($foursquare_option, '/')){
    preg_match("/[^/]+$/", $foursquare_option, $output_array);
    $foursquare_option = $output_array[0];
}

if(strpos($tripadvisor_option, '-d')){
    preg_match("/(?<=-d)(.*?)(?=-)/", $tripadvisor_option, $output_array);
    $tripadvisor_option = $output_array[0];
}

if(strpos($twitter_option, '/')){
    preg_match("/[^/]+$/", $twitter_option, $output_array);
    $twitter_option = $output_array[0];
}
```

The output was very unexpected....

```
$yelp_option = 'belved%C3%A8re-delft-2';
$foursquare_option = '2375308';
$tripadvisor_option = '4ad8dc0ff964a520601521e3';
$twitter_option = '2375308';
```

I tired for 1½ hour to move stuff around, comment out stuff... nothing seemed logical. Why does **$twitter_option become the same as $foursquare_option???**
is it because the regex pattern is the same? I tried adding a . to the twitter pattern so it look like so: `[^/]+.$` - now it's different but the regex should produce the same right? Still it became the same as $foursquare_option...

I tired flipping the order around so twitter preg_match executes before the foursquare one, but the result was not as I expected, I would think both variables would now be **duitdaging** but instead both was an empty string....

When I comment out the entire if(...){foursquare regex...} the twitter one works fine and produces **duitdaging**. But when I have both of them it just wont work.

I solved it easyli by changing the twitter sequence to so:

```
if(strpos($yelp_option, 'biz/')){
    preg_match("/(?<=biz\/).*/", $yelp_option, $output_array);
    $yelp_option = $output_array[0];
}

if(strpos($foursquare_option, '/')){
    preg_match("/[^/]+$/", $foursquare_option, $output_array);
    $foursquare_option = $output_array[0];
}

if(strpos($tripadvisor_option, '-d')){
    preg_match("/(?<=-d)(.*?)(?=-)/", $tripadvisor_option, $output_array);
    $tripadvisor_option = $output_array[0];
}

if(strpos($twitter_option, "/")){
    $pieces = explode("/", $twitter_option);
    $twitter_option = end($pieces);
}
```

so I don't use preg_match for both twitter and foursquare. This gave the right outcome

```
$yelp_option = 'belved%C3%A8re-delft-2';
$foursquare_option = '2375308';
$tripadvisor_option = '4ad8dc0ff964a520601521e3';
$twitter_option = 'duitdaging';
```

I'm still more confused than I have ever been so I just MUST ask this question. Does this seem logical to anyone?

- Happy friday x_x

Comment: `[^/]+$` is invalid, you need to escape the `/` as `[^\/]+$` (`[^\\/]+$` in PHP)

Comment: @ctwheels Maybe I don't understand the documentation correctly, but I'm seeing this: "*Note that / is not a special regular expression character.*" http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Comment: @JBD you don't *have* to escape it in PHP, but then you have to choose a different delimiter. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6076269/3600709

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Issue Explanation

Since you are using the delimiter `/` to enclose your regex pattern, you cannot use `/` in the regex explicitly. It must be escaped with `\`. There is another option in PHP and some other languages to use a different delimiter to enclose your pattern. Keep reading for more details.

#### Stackoverflow Sources

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6076269/3600709) for more details (quoted below).

> What context/language? Some languages use `/` as the pattern
>   delimiter, so yes, you need to escape it, depending on which
>   language/context. You escape it by putting a backward slash in front
>   of it: `\/` For some languages (like PHP) you can use other characters
>   as the delimiter and therefore you don't need to escape it. But AFAIK
>   in all languages, the only special significance the `/` has is it may
>   be the designated pattern delimiter.

#### PHP Documentation Sources

[See the link to the documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). The documentation states the following (note the last quoted section is of upmost importance/relevance to this question):

> When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is
>   enclosed by delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric,
>   non-backslash, non-whitespace character.
>
> Often used delimiters are forward slashes (/), hash signs (#) and
>   tildes (~). The following are all examples of valid delimited
>   patterns.
>
> ```
> /foo bar/
> #^[^0-9]$#
> +php+
> %[a-zA-Z0-9_-]%
> ```
>
> It is also possible to use bracket style delimiters where the opening
>   and closing brackets are the starting and ending delimiter,
>   respectively. (), {}, [] and <> are all valid bracket style delimiter
>   pairs.
>
> ```
> (this [is] a (pattern))
> {this [is] a (pattern)}
> [this [is] a (pattern)]
> <this [is] a (pattern)>
> ```
>
> Bracket style delimiters do not need to be escaped when they are used
>   as meta characters within the pattern, but as with other delimiters
>   they must be escaped when they are used as literal characters.
>  If
>   the delimiter needs to be matched inside the pattern it must be
>   escaped using a backslash. If the delimiter appears often inside the
>   pattern, it is a good idea to choose another delimiter in order to
>   increase readability.
>
> ```
> /http:\/\//
> #http://#
> ```

---

### Solution

#### Solution 1

This solution escapes the delimiter inside the regex using the backslash `\`.

```
if(strpos($yelp_option, 'biz/')){
    preg_match("/(?<=biz\/).*/", $yelp_option, $output_array);
    $yelp_option = $output_array[0];
}

if(strpos($foursquare_option, '/')){
    preg_match("/[^\\/]+$/", $foursquare_option, $output_array);
    $foursquare_option = $output_array[0];
}

if(strpos($tripadvisor_option, '-d')){
    preg_match("/(?<=-d)(.*?)(?=-)/", $tripadvisor_option, $output_array);
    $tripadvisor_option = $output_array[0];
}

if(strpos($twitter_option, '/')){
    preg_match("/[^\\/]+$/", $twitter_option, $output_array);
    $twitter_option = $output_array[0];
}
```

#### Solution 2

This solution uses a different delimiter to enclose the pattern `~`

```
if(strpos($yelp_option, 'biz/')){
    preg_match("~(?<=biz\/).*~", $yelp_option, $output_array);
    $yelp_option = $output_array[0];
}

if(strpos($foursquare_option, '/')){
    preg_match("~[^/]+$~", $foursquare_option, $output_array);
    $foursquare_option = $output_array[0];
}

if(strpos($tripadvisor_option, '-d')){
    preg_match("~(?<=-d)(.*?)(?=-)~", $tripadvisor_option, $output_array);
    $tripadvisor_option = $output_array[0];
}

if(strpos($twitter_option, '/')){
    preg_match("~[^/]+$~", $twitter_option, $output_array);
    $twitter_option = $output_array[0];
}
```

Comment: Very nice answer.