# How to add / into the preg_replace pattern for search highlighting keyword

Tags: php

In the search script I use this function:

```
function highlightkeyword($string, $keyword, $color = '#DE6E08') 
{
    return preg_replace("/($keyword)/i", sprintf('<span style="color: #fff; background-color: %s; padding: 0 0.225rem;">$1</span>', $color), $string);}
```

This should higlight searched word. But now I need to search for word: "FNPBH/E3" which contains forward slash.

This scripts finds the item but it does not display its name. It gives error as shown below.

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'E' in line: 27
```

How to deal with it? Any way of escaping?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping a forward slash in a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076229/escaping-a-forward-slash-in-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `preg_quote` function to escape `$keyword` before creating your regex.

Comment: tried: preg_replace("/(" . preg_quote($keyword) . ")/i" but it does not work either

Comment: $keyword = preg_quote($keyword, '/'); before function works ! Yippeee

Answer (score 0):

Change up your start and end brackets.  Instead of the forward slash `/` which is in your `$keyword` use a character you're not likely to find in your `$keyword` variable.  Like this:

`return preg_replace("!($keyword)!i", sprintf('<span style="color: #fff; background-color: %s; padding: 0 0.225rem;">$1</span>', $color), $string);`

The exclamation points `!` are now bracketing the regex.  Currently, the forward slash in the `$keyword` is cutting off your regex.

Comment: yes, it will work. SO should I use your solution or $keyword = preg_quote($keyword, '/'); before function

Comment: My solution offers a wider range of choices for your `$keyword` variable.  For example, you have to tell preg_quote which character you want it to ignore.  My solution by passes all these requirements and as long as your `$keyword` does not contain an `!` exclamation point, then you're going to get all possible results every time.  If this works for you, please mark my answer as the solution.  Thank you!