# regex - exclude substring contains more than 2 "/"

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have a list of the following strings:

```
/fajwe/conv_1/routing/apwfe/afjwepfj
/fajwe/conv_2/routing/apwfe
/fajwe/conv_2/routing
/fajwe/conv_3/routing/apwfe/afjwepfj/awef
/fajwe/conv_4/routing/apwfe/afjwepfj/awef/0o09
```

I want a regex to only match string contains no more than 1 `/` after the word `routing`. Namely `/fajwe/conv_2/routing/apwfe` and `/fajwe/conv_2/routing`.

Currently I use the regex `^((?!rou\w+(\/\w+){2,}).)*$` but it matches nothing. How can I write a regex to **exclude strings contains more than 2 `/`** after the word `routing`?

I would love to learn how to achieve this using **Negative Lookbehind**. Many thanks!

Comment: Why not use a simple regex like [`^.*?/routing/?[^/]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/b26Nw8/1/tests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex matches what you are looking for with the multiline flag `m` as [@revo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020526/revo) pointed out.

[`^((?!rou\w+(\/\w+){2,}).)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/P4zmwO/1)

You could also try it like this:

[`^\/fajwe\/conv_\d\/routing(?:\/[^\/]+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/zgt0Qf/2)

Depending of your context of language you could `\/` [escape the forward slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076229/escaping-a-forward-slash-in-a-regular-expression)

Comment: Yes it turned out that I forgot the `m` flag. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
^.*\/routing(\/[^\/]*){0,1}$
```

Comment: These both match the same thing `^.*\/routing(?:\/[^\/]*)?$`

Comment: thanks for your help! However I tested it on regex101 and it doesn't work.

Comment: You should enable multiline flag `m`. @spacegoing

Comment: @revo Thanks for your comment! It works! Would you please show me how to use Negative Lookbehind to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
routing(\/[^\/]*)?$
```

there you go

https://regex101.com/r/KjE8ed/1/