# php code that uses regex to replace a search phrase or search terms with <b> match </b>

Tags: php, html, regex

I need to highlight my site content based on a phrase like: "fire and water".  I need to put `<b>` tags around the phrase wherever it exists completely.  And if the words appear individually (not in complete form) they should get a `<b>` tag.  For example, if the content is:

> The world is made of three elements fire and water and air.  Fire is hot and water is wet.

The result should be:

> The world is made of three elements `<b>`fire and water`</b>` `<b>`and`</b>` air.  `<b>`Fire`</b>` is hot `<b>`and`</b>` `<b>`water`</b>` is wet.

I tried using:

```
$output = preg_replace("/("fire and water)/i", '`<b>`$1`</b>`', $content);   
$output = preg_replace("/(fire|and|water)/i", '`<b>`$1`</b>`', $ouput);
```

However this produces extra (and unwanted) `<b>` tags when the full phrase appears in the content causing a result like this:

> `<b><b>`fire`</b>` `<b>`and`</b>` `<b>`water`</b></b>`

I know this won't display any differently on the screen than

> `<b>`fire and water`</b>`

However, big problems are caused when the search phrase contains a ' / '.  There must be a way in regex to highlight the full phrase and individual words without doing both at once.

Comment: Please make sure the code examples do actually work.

Comment: As an aside, the world is made of four (classical) elements: earth, water, air and fire. But since [Earth Wind & Fire](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gs069dndIYk), who knows what to think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is probably much simpler than you thought:

```
$input  = 'The world is made of three elements fire and water and air. Fire is hot and water is wet.';

$output = preg_replace("/(fire and water|fire|and|water)/i", '<b>$1</b>',$input);

echo $output;
```

And the output is:

> The world is made of three elements **fire and water** **and**
>   air. **Fire** is hot **and** **water** is wet.

The source looks like this:

```
The world is made of three elements <b>fire and water</b> <b>and</b> air. <b>Fire</b> is hot <b>and</b> <b>water</b> is wet.
```

The elements are processed in the order they are in.

See also: [Escaping a forward slash in a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076229/escaping-a-forward-slash-in-a-regular-expression)