# Excluding anything with /!ut/ in the line using regex

Tags: regex

I would like to exclude any line in the document that has `/!ut/` 
I know `/` is a special character in regex so tried below and does not seem to be working as expected.

```
//!ut//
//(!ut)//
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to escape the forward slash in a regex, but you do [when it is used as a delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076229/escaping-a-forward-slash-in-a-regular-expression)

If you change your regexes to match a single forward slash with or without escaping them, `/!ut/` would match that literally and `/(!ut)/` would match that literally with `!ut` in a capturing group.

What you could do to exclude any line that contains `/!ut/` is to use a negative lookahead `(?!.*/!ut/)` to make sure that what follows is not `/!ut/` and then match the rest of the line using `.*$`

`^(?!.*\/!ut\/).+$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NVnNif/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape special characters.

```
/\/(!ut)\//
```

or

```
/\/!ut\//
```