# Jenkins git plugin: specify list of branches

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins UI I can specify using regular expression, which branches to poll in this job.

But I need to poll a list of concrete branches, i.e.

```
develop, feature1, feature2
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, use git plugin and set branch as parameter

Comment: @JoaoVitorino - I can put single branch or wildcard, but not comma separated list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In git parameter add a regex in Branch filter.

(develop|feature1|feature2)

[image]

[Git parameter plugin docs](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin)

Comment: It does not work :(
I put 
(origin/extracted-config|origin/develop)
And I get
"ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job."

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076229/escaping-a-forward-slash-in-a-regular-expression and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589074/regex-should-hyphens-be-escaped